# Why font awesome icon is not showing in the website ? Links for font-awesome-kit and icon added

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

My Portfolio

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/207456fad4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="sub-title">My Services</h1>
        <div class="services-list">
            <div>
            **  <i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i>**
            <h2>Web Design  </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet dui sit amet ex luctus congue in at tellus.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

I tried by adding font awesome css link in the head section.
but it doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Try these CDN links:

CSS in head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

JS before ending body tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-rpLlll167T5LJHwp0waJCh3ZRf7pO6IT1+LZOhAyP6phAirwchClbTZV3iqL3BMrVxIYRbzGTpli4rfxsCK6Vw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I hope it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I coudn't get a proper solution by searching and trying the answers i got from different platfroms.
Atlast i got answer by just adding a "fa" class in icon link.
Eg :It was like this before..

and i added "fa" class and tried.. then it WOKRS!!!  :)
 is the solution...